# BottomNavigationView switching between activities - solutions appear deprecated?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I am using a [BottomNavigationBar](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-bottom-navigation-with-activities-in-android/) and as per recent blogs and research, it seems the best way to flick between activities using this bar is to use the `setInNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

The issue is - this is deprecated.

> setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)'
> is deprecated

[Recent articles suggest](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-bottom-navigation-with-activities-in-android/) this is the way to allow changing between activities via a BottomNavigationBar and therefore I am not sure of alternative.

The deprecation doesn't appear to offer a good alternative that is safe to use. Can somebody suggest what would be non deprecated approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setOnItemSelectedListener()`

Like this

```
bottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
  when (menuItem.itemId) {
    R.id.home -> {
      return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
    }

    R.id.profile -> {
      return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
    }

    R.id.cart -> {
      return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
    }

  }
  false
}
```